# save file for 3D graphics applications from plot3d plot

Tags: r, plot, export, visualization, rgl

I have a data set 3D points (x,y,z). I plotted this data set with plot3Drgl and i wish to save a file in order to use this file with some 3D graphics software and show to my colleagues

```
library(plot3Drgl)
data <- data.frame(x=c(23,45,12,67,89,45,32,56,78,32),y=c(89,54,32,67,78,56,44,28,97,65),z=c(1,5,4,3,7,6,3,8,9))
        plot3d(z = data$z , x = data$x , y = data$y, pch=21,cex = 0.1,aspect = F,box = F,axes = F)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want. You could output a interactive HTML file

```
library(rgl)
browseURL(paste("file://", writeWebGL(dir=file.path(tempdir(), "webGL"), width=500), sep=""))
```

[image]

Or you could save your data to a csv to load and process it in another app:

```
write.csv(data, tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
cat(tf)
# C:\Windows\TEMP\RtmpApi4a2\file26dc359447f.csv
```

Comment: Thanks @LukeA. Is there a way to save the HTML code to send my email to my colleagues and say them to open with a browser? or i need to save the HTML file using google chrome for example?

Comment: Running the example, you save the necessary files in the directory webGL within the temporary directory. You can zip and mail it, or you can embedd the necessary libraries inline and mail the html.